# Conditional Compilation between ipad and iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, compilation, conditional-statements

As well as runtime checks for deciding on code paths for an iphone/ipad app, is there a conditional compilation flag anywhere that can be used to reduce code size? Apple seems to suggest it in their development notes, but I can't find anything anywhere.

How do others do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating an Universal app, that this will not make sense. Since the binary that gets executed on the iPad and iPhone are the same.

Comment: Ah! Right I see now. I assumed they were separate apps. I feel stupid now! Funny how the Apple docs suggest conditional compilation. Ah well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function and check for if `isPad` then do code for `iPad` else code for `iPhone`

```
- (BOOL) isPad{ 
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#else
    return NO;
#endif
}

if([self isPad])
{
//do code for iPad
}
else
{
//do code for iphone
}
```