# How to copy entire XCode project for another device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, project

Ok, I have an iPhone project that utilizes the camera.

I'm trying to utilize 80% of the same code for an iPad version of this project, however, I have to change some values as the camera quality in the latter device is messing with some parameters which I used as criteria for the first device.

So what I did was: I duplicated the iPhone project and had two targets in total, in the same project, the first one - for the iPhone (the original), and the second for the iPad.

When I clicked on the second target and added a comment on some .m file, the same comment appeared in the same .m file in the iPhone version's file too.

I don't want that - as you can see, I want a separation. I want to use the iPhone project as a base to modify the code of the iPad project. But how do I do this ? If the comment appeared in the iPhone .m too then obviously that means there is no distinction , and that whatever I do in the iPad .m will mess up the other .m ?

Answer (score 3):

it looks like your two projects are sharing the same files. If you want to keep them separate, just duplicate the source files and add them back to the projects individually.

Comment: How exactly would I go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a universal app. That way you can share all of your code between the two devices in a single project. Then you can simply separate logic for each device type into different files. So for example, have `ViewControllerA` for both device, and `ViewControllerA_iPhone` and `ViewControllerA_iPad` for the each separate device.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate:
[Conditional Compilation between ipad and iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497207/conditional-compilation-between-ipad-and-iphone)

I think you don't need a second implementation file, you just need to compile for a different device or check which one you are on at runtime and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think don't need to copy the entire project. You can just copy the necessary files only and create logical groups for iPhone and iPad. Check the device type into appdelegate class if it is iPad then call iPad related class else iPhone. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds to me like you need to 'extend' the functionality of the original to incorporate the new.

Would it not be easiest to create the 'interface' and then an base form of the class (maybe make it abstract), that implements all the methods, but leaves those that may have special needs (just have them throw an error as basic method functionality)

Then for the 2 projects you can extend the abstract class and overide the methods adding in the functionality that you require.

The beauty is that if there is an error condition in the overidden methods you can just call the 'superclass' abstract method and throw out the error message, you may decide that the super class method should take a string input variable to enable you to use a customised message taged onto the end of the one in the abstract class.

David

Comment: fair enough, I thought the principle would hold however of creating a library with basic functionality.