# xcode6 single storyboard but different images required

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios8

I making my first universal app using xcode6 with the single storyBoard. Usually I have two storyBoards - one for iPhone and one for iPad. Each storyBoard would have its relevent images.

But now, if I have UIImage as a background on the iPad, how can I have have a differnt uiImage on the iPhone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution # 1)***

You can use the "`UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM`" conditional to help you out.

Based on the [code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7497344/981049), all you'd need to do is set your UIImage to an outlet and then do something like:

```
- (BOOL) isPad{ 
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#else
    return NO;
#endif
}

if([self isPad])
{
    //do code for iPad
    [self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bigBackgroundImage"];
}
else
{
    //do code for iphone
    [self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallerBackgroundImage"];
}
```

***Solution # 2)***

You can indeed still use separate storyboards for iPad and iPhone.

To do this, you need to edit your app's info.plist file to show two different storyboard files for iPad and iPhone.  In Xcode 6.1, it looks like this:

[image: Two Separate Storyboard possiblities in the Info.plist file]

or, if you were editing the Info.plist file directly, you'd take out the original UIMainStoryboardFile` key and value and insert these two instead (rename the files to whatever you want them to be...)

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
<string>nameOfiPadStoryboard</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~iphone</key>
<string>nameOfiPhoneStoryboard</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I think I will miss seeing the representation of the 2 backgrounds on each storyBoard device. Is it possible to still implement 2 storyboards with Xcode6 ??

Comment: plus - if I did use  "UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM" would i have to set up the different frame sizes for each device ??

Comment: Yes, it is still possible to implement two storyboards with Xcode 6.  And I've attached screenshots and instructions that explains how.

Comment: Thanks Michael i really appreciate your help. I feel like its a step backwards not using the single storyBoard, but my universal app loads with lots of images so having 2 storyBoards seems the most logical way.